# Modulo strength , want explanation in the algorithm used to compute the answer

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve the problem Modulo strength at hackerearth ,
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/golf/modulo-strength-4/ , 
 so basically we have to find all such pairs of no. (say i,j) such that A[i]%k=A[j]%k where k is a no. given in the question , 
i tried brute force approach and got time limit exceeded at some of the last test cases and 
 in the discussion tab i found a code which is working but i couldn't understand what exactly it does, and the underlying thinking behind the algorithm used.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define int long long
int32_t main() {
    int n,k,s=0;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int a[n];
    vector<int>v(k,0);  // Specially this part ,what does it store?
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        cin>>a[i];
        v[a[i]%k]++;   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        s+=v[i]*(v[i]-1);
    }
    cout<<s;
}
```

Here is the code, i wanted to understand it so that i can apply this logic over other problems.

Comment: About the line in your comment, it just creates a 0-initialized vector of size `k`, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Actually i wanted to ask about what it stores logically throughout the program, like some frequency ?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour and uses a non-standard language extension.

Comment: One non standard extension is the variable length array but that doesn't matter if you are only going to use it will a compiler that accepts that extension, so I don't see that as a problem.  Even so, since the array is never used after it is filled, it is not needed and a normal variable would work as well.

Comment: Another non-standard extension is `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and that again isn't a problem as long as you know your code will ever only be used with GCC.  If it were code that you would use over and over then it might matter but the code will never be used after it is submitted and successfully scored so I don't see that as a problem either.

Comment: Here is a C++ program that doesn't use non-standard stuff: https://onlinegdb.com/VhceGn3kG   But the website given specifically says that it is a code-golf contest so the smallest code that runs successfully is scored higher which is why the standard headers aren't used and why all the variable names are one letter.  Even so, the example you give in your question isn't particularly short.  For example, if you are going to use the VLA GCC extension then don't use a vector that doesn't change size once it is allocated - use a VLA.

Comment: Here is a much more code-golfed version that does the same thing: https://onlinegdb.com/OCbpVRG6u  But you should ask a question on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ because they are experts at making things shorter.  If you do that remove all the whitespace and newlines like this:  https://onlinegdb.com/RT0pRnNbN which is 178 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with that;

- "bits/stdc++.h" is not a standard header
- Variable-length arrays, like `int a[n]`, are non-standard and prone to runtime errors (this one is also completely unnecessary)
- `#define int long long` makes the code have undefined behaviour.

Here is a fixed version, with some minor renaming and clarifying comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    long long n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    // There are k groups of friends.  
    std::vector<int> friends(k);
    // Count how many people there are in each group.  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        friends[x%k]++;   
    }
    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        // In a group of N mutual friends, each person has N-1 friends. 
        sum += friends[i] * (friends[i]-1);
    }
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's first go through with the purpose of every variable in the code.

The purpose of `n,k,s` is explicitly given.
`a[n]` is for reading the numbers in array.
`std::vector<int>v(k,0)` stores k sized vector of 0's, and `v[i]` indicates the number of variables in `a[n]` for which `a[j]%k==i`.

In the last loop, the following has done. The number of pairs that can be constructed with `n` elements is `n*(n-1)` (basic combinatorics), and if we have `v[i]` numbers for which the condition is satisfied and `a[j]%k==i` the number of pairs that can be constructed is `v[i]*(v[i]-1)`. The loop sums up the number of pairs for every remnant `i`.